# Ubuntu 14.04 Openstack single, error: Top-level container OS did not initialize correctly

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, openstack

During installation of openstack on Ubuntu server 14.04 x64, after I issue the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install openstack
sudo openstack-install
```

I get error: `Top-level container OS did not initialize correctly`
How can I solve it to install openstack correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error seems system specific , but there are a number of projects through which you can easily setup an openstack environment on your laptop.

1. DevStack [here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/guides/single-machine.html)
2. OSBash [here](https://github.com/openstack/training-labs)
3. Openstack Ansible [here](https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible)

I have setup the latest openstack on my laptop using Devstack.

Answer (score 0):

Please [follow this instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/Installer/debugging/single-install) to enable IP Forwarding, since `Top-level container OS did not initialize correctly` error means that you are running on a system using systemd and have configured it to use systemd-networkd, now you need to set `IPForward=yes` in the `[Network]` section of the `.network` file corresponding to the interface that reaches the outside world.

As an example, on this Wily system you should edit `/lib/systemd/network/80-container-host0.network`

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Match]
Virtualization=container
Name=host0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=yes

# Fix unresolvable network in LXC containers.
IPForward=yes
```

Comment: Hi, I must disappoint you. I don't have this file on my system. I also don't directory network in /lib/systemd.